# Upgrading GLX to version 1.3 on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, nvidia, upgrade, graphics, libraries

I have the following question: for the purpose of visualisation of some point clouds with GLFW library and Open3D, I would like to upgrade GLX to version 1.3 on Ubuntu 18.04. Having done some research on the Internet, I applied the most commonly advised solution:

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa`

`sudo apt-get update`

`sudo apt-get upgrade`

but to no avail - `glxinfo | grep version` still yields 1.2. Could it be driver-related? My graphics card is GeForce RTX 2070 and my driver is 460.32.03. I also seem to have the newest version of the Mesa library. I am running out of ideas and will greatly appreciate any help!

Comment: That PPA says "*Currently supported releases are Xenial/16.04 and Yakkety/16.10*" which is not your release...  https://launchpad.net/~xorg-edgers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa   You should look for solutions that support your release (and check PPAs before adding them as they're 3rd party sources with all security checks your responsibility).

Comment: @guiverc Good catch, thanks! Do any counterparts exist for Bionic, then? Is there a way to have GLX 1.3 on 18.04?